# Programmatically select UITableView cell not in current view

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

So it's easy to select a row that is currently in the UITableView. For example, to select the first row:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
                                animated:YES
                          scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Say that I have an array that is the data source for the table and the array count is greater than the number of cells displayed in the tableview. How can I get the `UITableView` to scroll to an index from the array that is beyond what is currently being displayed in the tableview?

All I am trying to do is to replicate programmatically what a user would do with their index finger as they scroll down the table.

My specific table displays 9 rows. My array has 20+ items. As the `UIViewController` loads, it retrieves the row number that should be selected (from an integer stored in `NSUserDefaults`). But I find that it will only scroll to the correct array position if that integer value is between 0 and 8. If it is 9 or greater, nothing happens, and I can't figure out how to make it respond to this. I've looked at all the `UITableViewDelegate` methods and none seems to address this.

What I've been doing to scroll and select a specific row is this (example arbitrarily selecting row 11):

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:11 inSection:0]
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                              animated:YES];

[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:11 inSection:0]
                            animated:YES
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Can anyone help me? I assume it isn't difficult, but I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you dequeueing cell for specific indexPath? Are you creating it yourself? Show some code :)

Comment: I just posted the code that I think will show what I am doing. Your question to me is a better way to ask my question: how to do I enqueue / dequeue the cells so that I can display a new subset from my array in the UITableView? That's what I don't know how to do. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you like to select a Cell that is not on screen? If you know which cell to select, you know what to perform on that selection and since that operation is not UI (as cell is not in view) thus just perform that operation.

Comment: I don't want to select cell that is not on screen. I want my screen to update the data that is being displayed to come from array positions not currently in the display. For example, if my table starts by displaying cells from array positions 0-8, maybe I want to update it to show array positions 11-19. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Your cells that are off the screen ain't selecting because you are using reusable cells. The cells from the visible screen will be used later, it isn't that all 100 cells are cached and each cell is responsible for each row. What it means is that they could or couldn't have something in it already. For example, lets say you have cell for row 1. When it comes off the screen, in the next few cells it will be reused as cell 15 or something, and if it had selected properties, it will still have it. It is like a new job and you get a desk from the developer before you - you could have desk with his trash, but it could also be clean.

I wouldn't select them as you select them by method, but in if statement in your cellForRowAtIndexPath. Something along the lines (added comments):

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // When using method with forIndexPath you don't have to check for nil because you will always get cell
    MyTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MyObj *obj = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.location.text = obj.location.location_description;
    // other formatting, text display, image loading, etc.

    if ([self.selectedObjects containsObject:obj]) {
        // do some selecting stuff
    } else {
        // but don't forget to unselect because you can get already selected cell
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**Edit:** To select invisible cell, first scroll to it, then select:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the concept (more or less), but I'm still struggling with how to execute it. What is `selectedObjects`?

Comment: My if is just a placeholder, because I don't know your whole structure. You can have indexes for selected cells, or maybe objects array. I went with the version of objects array - here we check if the cell should be selected or not - then style it accordingly or do some preparation or whatever - do it here, because when the cells gonna be visible, the method will be fired.

Comment: I'm still confused. My table view only allows a single cell to be selected, and I don't particularly care which one was previously selected. As an example, let's say that the `UIViewController` loads and wants to 'select' (i.e. display) the table starting with the object in array position 11 in the top cell (0) with cells 1-8 displaying the objects in array positions 12-19. I still have no idea how to do this. Sorry to be dense, but I just don't understand what I need to do to make this happen.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing! Unfortunately it's not working. This is way more complicated than it should be. Thanks for all of your help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom` instead of `UITableViewScrollPositionNone`

That is use this code

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0]
                                animated:YES
                          scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: for displaying 11 array element at top you can try scrolling the tableview to that particular index as   [_mainTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. My code was running in `viewDidLoad` which is too early. I needed to move it to `viewDidAppear`. At least I know that I am not losing my mind.